# How to set the hierarchy design of website in Google Search?

Tags: seo, google-search

I want to show my product in hierarchy in Google Search like:

[image: product view in hierarchy]

I tried keyword like "how to set product list in hierarchy through meta tags", but I did not find what I want.

How can I search this type of question in Google and how to set product design in hierarchy?

As above said this is repeated question but i already told that i tried keyword like how to set product design in hierarchy because i don't know specific keyword for it and i didn't copy it.

Comment: Sorry but i didn't copy the question i already told that i don't know specific keyword for it...

Comment: You also need to have site links setup in google's webmaster console, see answer in linked question by @unor for how to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its called as **Site Navigation** in Schema Markup, which allows you to help in SEO,

[image: Site Navigation Schema Markup]

Here is the code (microdata) for that

```
<ul itemscope itemtype="http://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement">
  <li itemprop="name"><a itemprop="url" href="http://www.example.com/our-advantage">Our Advantage</a></li>
  <li itemprop="name"><a itemprop="url" href="http://www.example.com/our-travel-experts">Travel Experts</a></li>
  <li itemprop="name"><a itemprop="url" href="http://www.example.com/destinations">Destinations</a></li>
  <li itemprop="name"><a itemprop="url" href="http://www.example.com/cruises">Cruises</a></li>
  <li itemprop="name"><a itemprop="url" href="http://www.example.com/interests">Interests</a></li>
  <li itemprop="name"><a itemprop="url" href="http://www.example.com/explore-your-world/interests/hotels-and-resorts">Hotels</a></li>
  <li itemprop="name"><a itemprop="url" href="http://www.example.com/travel-guides">Travel Resources</a></li>
</ul>
```

and refer the below link for more information

http://searchengineland.com/schema-markup-structured-data-seo-opportunities-site-type-231077